# Is there an elegant way to call a constructor with many arguments?

Tags: scala

I am reading a CSV file with many columns and turning every row into an object. It goes like this:

```
  val sighting = Sighting(
    cols(0).toInt,
    cols(1),
    cols(2),
    cols(3),
    cols(4),
    cols(5).toInt,
    cols(6),
    cols(7),
    cols(8),
    cols(9).toDouble
    cols(10),
    cols(11),
    cols(12))
```

This looks seriously ugly to me. Short of named parameters (which would be an improvement, granted), is there anything I can do to make it look less ugly?

Comment: Maybe look into [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/csv.scala). (That file is just an example; it has partial functionality)

Comment: You might add an auxiliary constructor to `Sighting` that takes a `Seq[String]` as it's only argument. Hide the ugliness inside that constructor, i.e. the `Seq` is unrolled, the `toInt`s added, and the primary constructor called.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
val sighting = cols match { case Seq(c0, c1, c2, ..., c12) => 
  Sighting(c0.toInt, c1, c2, ...)
}
```

Comment: That seems only marginally better

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the ugliness into a constructor which accepts an `Array`. I am aware that this doesn't reduce the level of ugliness, however still a better place to handle.

```
 object Sightings{

   def apply(array: Array[String]): Sightings = new Sightings(array(0), array(1), ...)

 }
```

Then you can use:

```
 val strings: Array[String] = line.split(",") //split the line and convert it into array of strings
 val sightings: Sightings = Sightings(strings) //create Sighting from the array
```